# Magento 2 How to Update Product Saleable qty using programmatically with Magento standard code

Tags: product, magento2.3, catalog, inventory, sku

How to Update Product **Saleable qty** using programmatically with Magento standard code ?

i am able to update product quantity using below code -

```
protected $_stockRegistry;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
)
{
    $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    parent::__construct();
}

public function customMethod() {
    $sku = 'xyz';
    $qty = 10;
    $stockItem = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
    $stockItem->setQty($qty);
    $this->_stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
}
```

using this code I am able to update product quantity but I need to update **saleable quantity** instead of product quantity